# Generate SQL queries with Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, hive

I want an easy way to generate SQL queries in Ruby. I know all about ActiveRecord, Sequel and DataMapper. I'm not looking for an ORM but just an easier way to generate SQL statement strings.

I'm using [RBHive](http://github.com/forward/rbhive) to run Hive queries and would like an easy way to generate the Hive query statements.

Surely this exists (AR, etc) and I've looked at [Arel](http://github.com/rails/arel), which seems promising. But can't figure out how to strip the SQL statement generation pieces off of the popular ORM libraries. Everything requires a connection to a database server.

Currently I just use raw SQL strings, but I want to get away from that as the queries are becoming more and more complex and error-prone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you're looking for Arel, which is used to build an AST for SQL statements and does not require a database connection.

The syntax is pretty different from what you're used to seeing, though. So be aware.

Read the README here to see if it makes sense to you:

https://github.com/rails/arel

Comment: I thought Arel looked right. In the end I just made an adapter for Hive in Sequel. Don't need to learn another syntax!

Answer (score 4):

You said

> Everything requires a connection to a database server.

I think, at least with Sequel you can use a dummy Database:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel::Database.new() #-> <Sequel::Database: >
puts DB[:test].sql          #-> SELECT * FROM "TEST"
```

Comment: Works for queries, for INSERT and UPDATE use insert_sql() and update_sql() instead of insert() and update(). Also the following constructor parameters are useful in case you detest "QUOTED_SHOUTY_IDENTIFIERS" like me: `Sequel::Database.new(quote_identifiers: false, identifier_input_method: nil)`.

Comment: Anyone arriving from the future who wants lowercase identifiers should use `DB = Sequel::Database.new; DB.extension :identifier_mangling; DB.identifier_input_method = nil; DB.identifier_output_method = nil` instead.